# Logstash is indexing only one row of select query from mysql to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to index data from mysql db to elasticsearch using logstash. Logstash is running without errors but the problem is, it indexing only one row from my SELECT query. 
Below are the versions of softwares I am using:

- elastic search : 2.4.1
- logstash: 5.1.1
- mysql: 5.7.17
- jdbc_driver_library: mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar

I am not sure if this is because logstash and elasticsearch versions are different.

Below is my pipeline configuration:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM employee"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "id"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "logstash"
        document_type => "sometype"
        document_id => "%{uid}"
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `tracking_column` (`id`) which you're using in the `jdbc` plugin and the `document_id` (`uid`) in the `output` is different. What if you have both of them same since it'll be easy to get all the records by `id` and push them into ES using the same `id` as well which could look more understandable:

```
document_id => "%{id}" <-- make sure you've got the exact spellings
```

And also please try adding this following line to your `jdbc` input after `tracking_column`:

```
tracking_column_type => "numeric"
```

Additionally to make sure that you don't have the `.logstash_jdbc_last_run` file existing when you're running the `logstash` file include the following line as well:

```
clean_run => true
```

So this is how your jdbc input should look like:

```
jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM employee"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "id"
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    clean_run => true
  }
```

Other than that the conf seems to be fine, unless you're willing to have [:sql_last_value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_state) where if you only wanted to update the newly added records in your database table. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I am not clear with few things. Every time the scheduler runs does it select all the rows and reindex (I understand it would not duplicate because we have tracking_column) in ES? For example, I have initially 10 rows in table and they are indexed in ES. Before scheduler runs next time, 5 more rows are added. Now, does scheduler pick 15 rows or 5 rows? My understanding is, if :sql_last _value is used in select query then 5 will picked otherwise, 15 will be picked. Please clarify my understanding.

Comment: @MaruthiPodila Yup that's right. If your sql_last_value points to the last updated id, it'll always pick the last 5 rows which have been added when the scheduler runs again.